# What are the most important PMD violations?

Tags: pmd

I am rolling out PMD to my project and the first run has fetched more than 4000 violations.  I would like to prioritize the violations and so am looking to filter the 100 most unacceptable violations that my team can focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the rule names and decide which is the most critical.  Or you can go through the available rules and only turn on the most critical.  Without knowing anything about your project or what rules are triggering, one can't say what is most important.  Plus, it is subjective.  A number of rules are equally fatal to an application.

In Eclipse, you can have it just run the highest severity rules which is a good proxy for what you are trying to accomplish.